# ng-click event with a promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have a angular app, that basically haves a directive that show the content depending the type of user, in case that your accountType is free it whos you a wizard modal giving you some promotional information to buy, but in case that your accounType isnt free or professional it lets the ng-click event be fired up and show the modal that your authorize to see.

But there is a problem that im getting, i believe that since i need to make a promise to get the current accounType of the user and than give the right information there is kind a type of the delay, the 2 models are fired up. Instead of showing one modal, i think is because the evt.stopProgation... is inside of a promise.

Here is my code:
directive:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('premiumContent',
        [
            '$http', '$q','UserService','$uibModal','$rootScope','WizardService',
            premium
        ]);


function premium($http, $q, UserService, $uibModal, $rootScope,WizardService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: -1,
        link: function($scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            element.on( 'click', function( evt ){

                var clean  = attrs.ngClick.substring(0, attrs.ngClick.indexOf('('));
                var controllerName = clean.substring(0, clean.indexOf('.'));
                var clickTarget = clean.substring(clean.indexOf('.'),clean.length).replace('.','');


                if(attrs.counter == "false"){
                    WizardService.isBlock = false;
                }else{
                    WizardService.isBlock = true;
                }

                UserService.getAuthenticatedUser()
                    .then(function (response) {
                        response = response.data;
                        debugger;


                        var accountType = response.user.account_type_id;
                        var user = response.user;
                        var users = $scope.$eval(attrs.to);



                        //check if is passing more than one user (array/object)
                        if(typeof users === 'object'){
                            if(users.indexOf(accountType) !== -1){

                                //assign a user to hide
                                users = users[users.indexOf(accountType)];
                            }
                        }

                        if(users  !== accountType) {
                            evt.preventDefault()
                            evt.stopImmediatePropagation();

                                $uibModal.open({
                                    animation: true,
                                    backdrop: 'static',
                                    keyboard: false,
                                    templateUrl: 'template/sidebar/wizard',
                                    size: 'lg',
                                    controller: 'WizardController',
                                    controllerAs: 'wizardCtrl',
                                    resolve: {
                                        user: function () {
                                            return user
                                        },
                                        modalName: function () {

                                            return $scope[controllerName][clickTarget];
                                        }

                                    }

                                });



                        }

                    });





            });
        }
    };
}
```

html:

```
<a premium-content to="[5]" counter="false" ng-click="sidebarCtrl.openProModal();">Senstive data</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The .open method of $uibModal returns a modal instance which has property called result which is a promise.  To implement this your code should look like this:

```
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false,
    templateUrl: 'template/sidebar/wizard',
    size: 'lg',
    controller: 'WizardController',
    controllerAs: 'wizardCtrl',
    resolve: {
        user: function () {
                 return user
              },
        modalName: function () {
                 return $scope[controllerName][clickTarget];
              }
     }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function() {
    // do something here
});
```

Comment: i dont quite understand what i put in the modalInstance.result, could you explain please?

Comment: You can pass a value (maybe accounType?) back from the modal and handle it here or whatever code that you would want to execute after the modal is closed.